# Error in showing products by shortcodes on my static home page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In my static home page i have selected full width home page option and i want to show featured products by shortcodes. I used this shortcode to show my featured product. `[featured_products per_page="12" columns="4"]`.   But there is some error. The products are showing in irregular Pattern. They are not parallel to each other. The height is very big. And background becomes grey.  I have also tried the plugin named  woocommerce product slider. But there was similar error.  You can go to my website and see the problem. I have used both, the shortcode and the plugin on my static home page. `store.codebla.com` Please please please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: I know. my english is not good. :)

Comment: The problem's not with your English.  The problem is that you're not giving us enough information in your question to help you to solve the problem.

Comment: Ok..   i am adding more information. Thanks

Comment: Please make sure you go through the checklist and make sure all of the relevant points are covered.

Comment: My problem is solved...